# How do I fix this VLOOKUP that returns last row value for date lookup?

Tags: vlookup, microsoft-excel-2011

I am running into what seems to be a very basic issue with Excel's VLOOKUP function (Mac Excel 2011). I've downloaded historical stock prices from [Google Finance for Microsoft](https://www.google.ca/finance/historical?cid=358464&startdate=Dec+15%2C+1994&enddate=Dec+6%2C+2014&num=30&ei=vIqDVODXApGwsQeMvYGoDg) and then copied that into an Excel sheet.

When I try to VLOOKUP the closing price for a specific date, the result is always the last closing price in the column, or an error. I am not at all sure how to address it.

[Screenshot of Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWSwm.jpg)

[My File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/unvts1xefikapea/VLOOKUP_Bug.xlsm?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things I see,

1. Your `VLOOKUP` formula is incomplete. It needs the `Range Lookup`
   identified as `TRUE` for an approxomate match or `FALSE` for exact.
   Without at least the `,` after the column number you will get a
   `#N/A` error.
2. Make sure the lookup value and the date column are formatted the
   same. Otherwise, Excel may not match them if one is text and the
   other is a date.

I used your data and the following formula without error.

```
=VLOOKUP(J10,B6:G12,5,)
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked. Thank you for your help.